# Eclipse removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <Button> Android AAPT

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I've researched for a good several hours and still could not solve this.

Recently, I had a project in which I had to work on eclipse. Given that I almost have no experience in eclipse, I went ahead and imported it in Android Studio. Everything went well. The project was done, apk's were being built and shipped until it came to the point where I had to migrate the code back to eclipse, because the guy said so.

So I followed [this guide](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/importing-android-studio-projects-into-eclipse.html) that I found on another SO question. Java files, resources and assets were successfully moved over. Then, I built it. That's when this error showed up:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <Button>   activity_main_menu.xml  /Splash/res/layout  line 41 Android AAPT Problem
note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <Button>   activity_main_menu.xml  /Splash/res/layout  line 53 Android AAPT Problem
note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <Button>   activity_main_menu.xml  /Splash/res/layout  line 65 Android AAPT Problem
note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <Button>   activity_main_menu.xml  /Splash/res/layout  line 77 Android AAPT Problem
note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <RelativeLayout> activity_main_menu.xml  /Splash/res/layout  line 11 Android AAPT Problem
note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentStart from <Button>   activity_main_menu.xml  /Splash/res/layout  line 29 Android AAPT Problem
```

It pointed me to an xml file. I tried to remove almost every error and it kept going and going until I think to the point where I have to delete the project itself. I tried targeting different API levels and adjusted minimum API to API 16 (Kitkat). I checked project.properties and made sure it pointed at `android-22`. Cleaned and rebuilt, and actually did the import again to no avail. Hopefully you can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Note: All of it works in Android Studio perfectly.

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:minWidth="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
        android:onClick="newAcct"
        android:text="Add account" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
        android:onClick="addTX"
        android:text="Add Transaction" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
        android:onClick="searchTX"
        android:text="View Transaction" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
        android:onClick="listAcc"
        android:text="View Accounts" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
        android:onClick="recentTX"
        android:text="View Recent Transactions" />
</RelativeLayout>
```